# Angularjs/Laravel POST returns 500 internal server error

Tags: angularjs, http, laravel, eloquent

I know this has been asked a lot, but I can't seem to find the error.
To start things off, is there any possibility I can laravel let display an more specefic error than 500 Internal Server? Because I just assume I pass in wrong data now, but I can't be sure ...

The data I post:

```
Vertrekpuntvallt=50.93766174471314&Vertrekpuntvallng=3.8891601562499996&Eindpuntvallt=51.07246834624617
&Eindpuntvallng=3.592529296875&name=blablabla&description=beschrijvint+blabla&ridedate=Sat+Oct+10+2015
+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0200+(CEST)&ridetime=Thu+Jan+01+1970+11%3A11%3A11+GMT%2B0100+(CET)&ridepersons=3
&ridevertrekpunt=Svhool&rideeindpunt=Dinge
```

My Submitfunction (not returning specefic error):

```
        $scope.submitRide = function() {
            Ride.save($scope.rideData)
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("Da hebe hij goed gedaan jong!");
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    console.log("nope");
                    console.log(error);
                });
    };
```

My Controller:

```
    public function store(StoreRideRequest $request)
{
    $todo = Ride::create($request->all());
    return $todo;
}
```

My SoreRideRequest Rules:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'ridedate' => 'date',
//Update: 'ridetime' => 'time' is not possible!! Still not fixed though :D
        //'ridetime' => 'time',
        'ridepersons' => 'required',
        'ridevertrekpunt' => 'required',
        'rideeindpunt' => 'required',
        'Vertrekpuntvallt' => 'required',
        'Vertrekpuntvallng' => 'required',
        'Eindpuntvallt' => 'required',
        'Eindpuntvallng' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

And finally my model:

```
   protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description',
    'ridedate',
    'ridetime',
    'ridepersons',
    'ridevertrekpunt',
    'rideeindpunt',
    'Vertrekpuntvallt',
    'Vertrekpuntvallng',
    'Eindpuntvallt',
    'Eindpuntvallng'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
];

protected $dates = [
    'ridedate'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Update: I will also post a portion of my db:

```
            // Data
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->date('ridedate');
        $table->time('ridetime');
        $table->tinyInteger('ridepersons');
        $table->string('ridevertrekpunt');
        $table->string('rideeindpunt');
        $table->float('Vertrekpuntvallt');
        $table->float('Vertrekpuntvallng');
        $table->float('Eindpuntvallt');
        $table->float('Eindpuntvallng');


        // Foreign Keys
        $table->integer(CreateRidesTable::FK)
            ->unsigned();
        $table->foreign(CreateRidesTable::FK)
            ->references(CreateRidesTable::PK)
            ->on(CreateUsersTable::TABLE)
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

I know there is some wrong data here? But I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Check the logs in storage/logs/ or enable debug in your .env file, you should get the error and stack trace in the response

Comment: Hi, the debug is already enabled. I didn't knew about the log files though (gonna take me some time to understand them I'm afraid), but this is already really helpfull!